# python , I got this message in pycharm while coding as output :TypeError: can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator

Tags: list, average

I am trying to evaluate the average of list in a list  and here is the code:

```
from statistics import mean


lst = [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]]

total_avg = mean(lst)
print("The average is ", round(total_avg ,2))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full  traceback error.  Though, with a quick glance,  the mean() function expects a list of values.  What you have are a list of lists.  I don't think ```mean``` allows that.

Comment: what is the language? Use the tags provided.

Comment: what is the language? it is python

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you have not unpacked the list of lists. You have to unpack it first.
In your code the input for the `mean()` function would be `[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]`, instead of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

```py
import statistics

lst = [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]]

lst = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]

total_avg = statistics.mean(lst)
print("The average is ", round(total_avg ,2))
```

Comment: ok thanks for your comment , I will try it